# Not receiving payment_status = Completed

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have setup a php script to work with the paypal IPN.  Overall things work, but I'm not getting some of the variables the documentation says I will be receiving:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#protocol_and_arch

Most notably I'm not getting anything returned for Payment_status which it says should be returned as Completed.

I'm doing a monthly or yearly recurring payment option with a free one month trial.  I'm wondering if this could be the culprit?  If it is, what else can I do to verify the user has in fact completed the process of supplying payment information properly to paypal to start the trial period?  I can't find any variable in the set that identifies this (as opposed to a declined transaction, or a subscription cancellation, or a totally faked entry).

Also, it's not anywhere near as important; but i'm not getting back a transaction id (txn_id), and the referenced variable mc_gross is also missing.  Although it is giving me the monthly renewal rate in a variable called mc_amount3.

Lastly, is there a listing of what the possible results are for each possible variable somewhere?  For instance, I randomly get back subscription period as "period3 = 1 M", which I assume means 1 Month.  But how am I supposed to know what the other options are?  Would a year renewal be 1 Y?  Or something else entirely?

A little frustrated right now so I'd appreciate it if anyone who had similar issues can provide some insight.

Comment: Did you manage to find why `payment_status` is missing and variables are different ? I seem to have same problem, I receive strange variables to my IPN script. E.g missing `mc_gross` but receiving things like `mc_amount3`

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a couple days I finally ponied up for a tech support call to paypal.  The lady literally knew less than I did which was disappointing.  I still, can't get a direct answer on why I'm not seeing the same variables their basic setup page states I should be looking for.

However, after another couple days of looking i at least found the IPN variable reference guide buried DEEP in the paypal help pages.

Thought I'd post the link in case anyone comes across this page looking for similar answers:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/